# Call multiple hook inserts from different modules?

Tags: 6, hooks, nodes

Is it possible for two modules that interact with one another to both call `hook_insert()`?

- I have a node type that calls `ModuleA_insert()` when the user hits the 'save' button.
- Module B is a custom comment-like module that gets injected into a form. In module B, I have a `ModuleB_insert()`, but it never runs.
- I am trying to keep module A from having to deal with the inserts/updates from module B.

I can get module B to insert by using `hook_nodeapi()`, but it would be easier if I could get `hook_insert()` to work, meaning module A and module B's data and actions are separated from each other - not to mention the overhead cost of having `hook_nodeapi()` run and check every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb: Don't call hook_anything() in other modules. :-)

If you call `node_save($yourNode)` then the node API will invoke `hook_insert()` in the module that implements that node type, if the node is being inserted. Otherwise `hook_update()` gets called for updates.

If you need to act on an insert for any type of node, and it sounds like you do, then you want to implement `hook_nodeapi()`.

[Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) has a [node](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/node_example--node_example.module/group/node_example/6) project and a [nodeAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example--nodeapi_example.module/group/nodeapi_example/6) project, so you can figure out which you need.

Comment: Are you saying do not ever use hook_anything() from my custom module?

Comment: I'm saying the node API will call the hook, so that your module can do what it needs to after the node is inserted (or updated, as the case may be). hook_insert() is supposed to be implemented by the module that creates the node type. hook_nodeapi() is called for any module that has it, so that those modules can then do whatever they want with the node.